# Making a slider with BEM CSS

Tags: html, css, sass, bem

So if I was to use BEM to create a slider would it look like this:

```
              <div class="slideshow">
               <div class="slide slide--slide01"></div>
               <div class="slide slide--slide02"></div>
               <div class="slide slide--slide03"></div>
               <div class="slide slide--slide04"></div>
              </div>
```

or:

```
             <div class="slideshow">
              <div class="slide slideshow__slide01"></div>
              <div class="slide slideshow__slide02"></div>
              <div class="slide slideshow__slide03"></div>
              <div class="slide slideshow__slide04"></div>
             </div>
```

Please fill me in and explain

Answer (score 1):

Elements generally get their name from the block they're nested in. Therefore, I would argue that neither example one nor two is correct in this case.

My initial thought would have the layout as such:

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <div class="slideshow__item"></div>
    <div class="slideshow__item"></div>
    <div class="slideshow__item"></div>
    <div class="slideshow__item"></div>
</div>
```

If each of the slides will be slightly different from one another, you would use the modifiers as such:

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <div class="slideshow__item slideshow__item--slide1"></div>
    <div class="slideshow__item slideshow__item--slide2"></div>
    <div class="slideshow__item slideshow__item--slide3"></div>
    <div class="slideshow__item slideshow__item--slide4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements are delimited with two (2) underscores (__), and Modifiers are delimited by two (2) hyphens (--).

In your case you should use two underscores (__).

[Original article](https://cssguidelin.es/#bem-like-naming)